# Can I manually trigger observers of specific properties in MobX?

Tags: javascript, mobx

I have an object that has some observable attributes that are persisted in cookies:

```
class MyClass {
  @observable attribute = Cookies.get("attribute");

  @action updateAttribute(newValue) {
    this.attribute = newValue;
    Cookies.set("attribute", newValue);
  }
}

var obj = new MyClass();
```

This is obviously not ideal because now I'm keeping data in two places (the attribute and the cookie). Ideally, I would love to do something like this:

```
class MyClass {
  @computed get attribute() {
    return Cookies.get("attribute");
  }

  @action updateAttribute(newValue) {
    Cookies.set("attribute", newValue);
    // Somehow mark the computed property `this.attribute` as dirty.
  }
}
```

A solution like this might work:

```
class MyClass {
  @observable _version = 0;

  @computed get attribute() {
    // Read `this._version` to create the dependency.
    this._version;
    return Cookies.get("attribute");
  }

  @action updateAttribute(newValue) {
    Cookies.set("attribute", newValue);
    this._version++;
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is actually pretty nice. Another solution is to "read" the cookie only once, when starting, and after that use autorun to store the cookie:

```
class MyClass {
  @observable attribute = Cookie.get("attribute")

  constructor() {
    autorun(() => Cookie.set("attribute", this.attribute))
  }
}
```

Comment: That's neat. Will the autorun be automatically disposed of, or do you have to store the disposer and e.g. implement a custom `destroy`-method?

Comment: Very nice! I like this 

Comment: you should dispose it indeed